# I have an xml code that needs dceciphering

Tags: xml

I have an xml document from a text messaging app that no longer exists.  I need help deciphering the date for each text message.  This was a text that was sent the evening of the presidential elections on 11/8/16. If I can figure out the format then I can decipher the dates for the rest of the text messages.

```
"date": 1478664774176
```

Comment: I deciphered the date, please check if the month is wrong. you can reach out to me at dannislife6@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

That value is likely a [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

If so, then according to [epochconverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com/):

> Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:
>
> GMT: Wednesday, November 9, 2016 4:12:54.176 AM
>
> Your time zone: Tuesday, November 8, 2016 11:12:54.176 PM GMT-05:00
>
> Relative: 5 years ago

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for!